# usage of RSA_NO_PADDING when decrypting data with RSA private key using openssl libcrypto

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa, libcrypto

I generated RSA private key and public key as below,

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in pri.key -out pub.key
```

And encrypted text file as below,

```
openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey ~/pub.key -in ~/1.txt -out ~/1e.txt
```

Then I wrote below program to decrypt the encryted file. However, it seemed that decrypt didn't work as  expected.

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void
cleanup()
{
    EVP_cleanup();
    CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
    ERR_free_strings();
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OPENSSL_config(nullptr);

    cout<<"Initialize crypto library done"<<endl;

    EVP_PKEY * key = EVP_PKEY_new();
    if (key == nullptr) {
        cout<<"Failed to contruct new key"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    FILE * fpri = nullptr;
    fpri = fopen("/home/stack/pri.key", "r");
    if (fpri == nullptr) {
        cout<<"Failed to load private key"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    key = PEM_read_PrivateKey(fpri, &key, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (key == nullptr) {
        std::cout<<"Read private key failed"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout<<"load private key successfully"<<endl;
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = nullptr;
    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(key, nullptr);
    EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(ctx);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_NO_PADDING);

    size_t outlen = 0, inlen = 0;
    unsigned char * out = nullptr, * in = nullptr;

    char buf[1024];
    FILE * fe = nullptr;
    fe = fopen("/home/stack/1e.txt", "r");
    size_t len = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf),  fe);
    cout<<"data input length is "<<len<<endl;
    EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, NULL, &outlen, in, inlen);
    cout<<"outlen is "<<outlen<<endl;

    out = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(outlen);
    EVP_PKEY_decrypt(ctx, out, &outlen, in, inlen);
    cout<<"decrypted data "<<out<<endl;
    cleanup();

    return 0;

}
```

When executing the code, the result is as below,

```
[stack@agent ~]$ ./test
Initialize crypto library done
load private key successfully
data input length is 256
outlen is 256
decrypted data
```

It seemed the decrypted data length was not correct and not printable.

When I commented out the instruction "EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_NO_PADDING);", it worked well.

I also tried with RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING, it didn't work either. If RSA PADDING is not set, it worked.

My question is as below,

1. Which padding is used in following command?

   ```
   openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey ~/pub.key -in ~/1.txt -out ~/1e.txt
   ```
2. Is padding necessary for RSA encrypt/decrypt? If so, how could I apply the padding mechanism?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/pkeyutl.html) doesn't say which padding is used by default. I would think it's PKCS#1 padding.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I tried to use PKCS#1 padding to decrypt firstly, and it didn't work.
 Then I guessed that no padding is used and use RSA_NO_PADDING to decrypt, it didn't work either. But after I commented the instruction for setting rsa_padding, it worked. Although my code works now, I still don't quite understand why.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I checked openssl source code. I understand it now, PKCS#1 is default padding mode.

Comment: If you looked into the code, then you can probably provide a more extensive answer than the currently accepted one. Think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding` if you use not default padding in openssl pkeyutl encryption. See [openssl pkeyutl documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/pkeyutl.html) for details about `-rsa_padding_mode`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I checked source code, PKCS#1 is default padding mode.